# What is the most efficient way to display 4 million 2D squares in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, webgl

My display has a resolution of 7680x4320 pixels. I want to display up to 4 million different colored squares. And I want to change the number of squares with a slider. If have currently two versions. One with canvas-fillRect which looks somethink like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < num_squares; i ++) {

   ctx.fillStyle = someColor;
   ctx.fillRect(pos_x, pos_y, pos_x + square_width, pos_y + square_height);

   // set pos_x and pos_y for next square
}
```

And one with webGL and three.js. Same loop, but I create a box geometry and a mesh for every square:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( width_height, width_height, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < num_squares; i ++) {

   var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } );
   material.emissive = new THREE.Color( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );

   var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

}
```

They both work quite fine for a few thousand squares. The first version can do up to one million squares, but everything over a million is just awful slow. I want to update the color and the number of squares dynamically.

Does anyone has tips on how to be more efficient with three.js/ WebGL/ Canvas?

## EDIT1: Second version: This is what I do at the beginning and when the slider has changed:

```
// Remove all objects from scene
            var obj, i;
            for ( i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i -- ) {
                obj = scene.children[ i ];
                if ( obj !== camera) {
                    scene.remove(obj);
                }
            }

            // Fill scene with new objects
            num_squares = gui_dat.squareNum;

            var window_pixel = window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight;
            var pixel_per_square = window_pixel / num_squares;
            var width_height = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(pixel_per_square));

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( width_height, width_height, 0);

            var pos_x = width_height/2;
            var pos_y = width_height/2;

            for (var i = 0; i < num_squares; i ++) {

                //var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,  );

                var material = new THREE.Material()( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } );
                material.emissive = new THREE.Color( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );

                var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                object.position.x = pos_x;
                object.position.y = pos_y;

                pos_x += width_height;
                if (pos_x > window.innerWidth) {

                    pos_x = width_height/2;
                    pos_y += width_height;
                }

                scene.add( object );

            }
```

Comment: What about http://www.pixijs.com/ ? It's a 2D accelerated framework.
I think that 4 million it's a very huge number for today's computing capacity...

Comment: how many squares can the second display?

Comment: Only update what has changed? Would help if few squares change per second. Canvas will be slow for many fillRects. For the THREE method, are you recreating the box each frame? I think webgl should be much faster even with millions of boxes. Could you share more of the code, your eventloop so to speak?

Comment: @gaitat: About 20,000.

Comment: @pcguru: I create the box at the beginning and when the slider has changed. The function is only called when mouse stops slider dragging. More code added

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `BoxGeometry` instead of `PlaneGeometry` and maybe even `PlaneBufferGeometry`?

Comment: @gaitat: Oh... No I didn't know PlaneGeometry exists. I will change that, thank you!

Comment: @gaitat: That helped, but creating more than one million still needs some minutes

Comment: What monitor are you using that will display 7680x4320 pixels? If your user's monitors cannot display the incredible amount of pixels that your monitor can, perhaps you might limit your rectangles to the actual display size of your user's screen.

Comment: I dont know if this will help but it is a good read anyway: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/

Comment: @markE: I use 4 monitors. The plan was that the visualization works for this specific setup and everyone else.

Comment: Use one geometry and do all the work in a fragment shader?

Comment: If you don't need to do much, just change the number of squares, I think doing it with a webgl canvas and a fragment shader is the way to go. No geometry or Three.js needed. [HERE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_fundamentals/) is a tutorial which would get you most of the way.

Comment: @BenGannaway: Thank you, I have a working version for random squares and it's quite fast. But now I'm stuck again, because I want the squares to have specific colors. But WebGL doesn't support sbo's. I'm not sure how I allocate the right color for my current pixel. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you're using a fragment shader, its just gl_FragColor = vec4(r,g,b,o);
What logic are you using to decide on pixel color?

Comment: @BenGannaway: One square represents one Wikipedia article and I want to map the number of changes made by users to the opacity. I have the data but I need to get it to the shader somehow.

Comment: You'll probably want to pass an array of values as one of the shader uniforms
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types

Comment: Or maybe a data texture: 
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/DataTexture

Comment: Why would someone draw 4 million squares in a web browser?

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to draw squares is to use the gl.POINTS primitive and then setting gl_PointSize to the pixel size.

In three.js, gl.POINTS is wrapped inside the THREE.PointCloud object.
You'll have to create a geometry object with one position for each point and pass that to the PointCloud constructor.

Here is an example of THREE.PointCloud in action: 
http://codepen.io/seanseansean/pen/EaBZEY

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {

    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    vertex.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    vertex.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;

    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}

...

materials[i] = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({size:size});
particles = new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, materials[i]);
```

I didn't dig through all the code but I've set the particle count to 2m and from my understanding, 5 point clouds are generated so 2m*5 = 10m particles and I'm getting around 30fps.

Answer (score 2):

The highest number of individual points I've seen so far was with potree.

http://potree.org/, https://github.com/potree

Try some demo, I was able to observe 5 millions of points in 3D at 20-30fps. I believe this is also current technological limit.

I didn't test potree on my own, so I cant say much about this tech. But there is data convertor and viewer (threejs based) so should only figure out how to convert the data.

Briefly about your question

The best way handle large data is group them as quad-tree (2d) or oct-tree (3d). This will allow you to not bother program with part that is too far from camera or not visible at all.

On the other hand, program doesnt like when you do too many webgl calls. Try to understand it like this, you want to do create ~60 images each second. But each time you set some parameter for GPU, program must do some sync. Spliting data means you will need to do more setup so tree must not be too detialed.

Last thing, someone said:

> You'll probably want to pass an array of values as one of the shader uniforms

I dont suggest it, bad idea. Texture lookup is quite fast, but attributes are always faster. If we are talking about 4M points, you cant afford reading data from uniforms.

Sorry I cant help you with the code, I could do it without threejs, Im not threejs expert :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying pixi framework( as mentioned in above comments ).

It has webgl renderer and some benchmarks are very promising.

http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark_v3/

It can handle allot of animated sprites.
If your app only displays the squares, and doesnt animate, and they are very simple sprites( only one color ) then it would give better performance than the demo link above.